# angular factory not getting set

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As you can see(below) I have a factory provider which I inject into another factory. There, I attempt to set one of the values on `infoPMIDs`. This is not working. Somehow, when I call `infoPMIDs` in a controller it still has the values `a = '', b = '', c = ''`

```
summariesApp.factory('infoPMIDs', [function () {
    var a = '', b = '',
        c = '';
    return {
        a: a,
        b: b,
        c: c
    }
}]);

summariesApp.factory('getPMIDs', ['infoPMIDs', function (infoPMIDs) {
    return function (Tab, other, drug) {
        var value = ['value1', 'value2'];
        infoPMIDs.genePhenotype = value;
    }    
}]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: infoPMIDs only returns a, b, c and doesnt allow you to set any values..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to update a,b,c in infoPMIDs then you'll have to expose some functionality to do so:

```
.factory('infoPMIDs', [function () {
    var a = '', b = '', c = '';
    return {
        a: a,
        b: b,
        c: c,
        setA: function(val){
            a = val;
        },
        setB: function(val){
            b = val;
        },
        setC: function(val){
            c = val;
        },
    }
}]);
```

or something similar